# REACT JS, how to DELETE DATA without refreshing page using useLoaderData() react router v6++

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

My goal is when I delete some data on my table it prevent from refreshing using the new version of `userLoadData` from `react-router-dom@6`.

I tried this I created some function `products()` with inside `useLoaderData`, it's working and deleting the data, but the problem is it's not refreshing when I delete. I need to refresh the page to update.

I will show my code that I've tried. Here is my component `Product` with my export const `ProductData`.

```
import { useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom";
import axiosClient from "../../../axios-client"

export const ProductData = () => {
  return axiosClient.get('admin/product')
    .then(({ data }) => {
      return data.data
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return error
    })
}

export default function Product() {
  const products = () => {
    return useLoaderData()
  }

  const ProductDelete = async(id) => {
    await axiosClient.delete('admin/product/delete/'+id)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        products()
      })
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      <table className="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-500">
        <thead className="bg-red-500">
          <tr>
            <th>id</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody className="divide-y divide-gray-200">
          {products() && products().map((product) => (
            <tr key={product.id}>
              <td className="px-6 py-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-800 whitespace-nowrap">
                <button onClick={()=>ProductDelete(product.id)}>Delete</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my router

```
import Product, { ProductData } from "./components/admin/product/IndexProduct"

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "product",
    element: <Product />,
    loader: ProductData
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic gist is that you should also provide a route `action` that issues the DELETE request, which will trigger the `Route` to revalidate itself and call the `loader` and refetch updated data.

Example:

```js
import { useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom";
import axiosClient from "../../../axios-client"

export const productsLoader = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axiosClient.get('admin/product')
    return data.data;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  };
};

export const deleteProductAction = async ({ request }) => {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const id = formData.get("productId");
  axiosClient.delete(`admin/product/delete/${id}`);
};
```

Import the `Form` component and wrap the delete button to submit the form and trigger the form/route action. Below uses a hidden form field to "inject" the product id that you want to work with.

```
import { Form, useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Product() {
  const products = useLoaderData();

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      <table className="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-500">
        <thead className="bg-red-500">
          <tr>
            <th>id</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody className="divide-y divide-gray-200">
          {products.map((product) => (
            <tr key={product.id}>
              <td className="px-6 py-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-800 whitespace-nowrap">
                <Form method="delete" replace>
                  <input name="productId" defaultValue={product.id} hidden />
                  <button type="submit">Delete</button>
                </Form>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Import the loader and action functions and add them to the `"/product"` route

```
import Product, {
  deleteProductAction,
  productsLoader
} from "./components/admin/product/IndexProduct"

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "product",
    element: <Product />,
    loader: productsLoader,
    action: deleteProductAction,
  }
]);
```

Demo using "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/" APIs.

[image: Edit react-js-how-to-delete-data-without-refreshing-page-using-useloaderdata-react]

Comment: thank you for editting my question, im not good at english grammar. and also thank you for answering my question it help me a lot. and thank you for discussing and explaining i understood now how work the loader function